# php CI webapp fails with 404 while trying to load css file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following code in a view for my codeigniter application:

```
 <link href="<?php echo APPPATH.'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

This is giving me a 404. 
However, a few lines down, I tried this to troubleshoot:

```
<?php echo APPPATH.'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' ?>
```

That shows the following path on my webpage:

> /var/www/html/testapp/application/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css

If I copy that path and paste it into a new browser window, it returns the contents of my css file.
I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

Tips?

Comment: You are confusing file system paths and URLs.

Comment: @CBroe currently looking into base_url() method to see what that gives me.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

*(In response to the helpful comment)*

`base_url()` requires the URL Helper to be loaded which can be done one of two ways.

Loaded in a controller

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Or, set to autoload in /application/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Comment: The only other comment to add to your answer would be to either enable the uri helper in the config or to add it directly in the controller in question.

Answer (score 0):

If the path you get printed by the 2nd line you've given is correct, then it might be the slash at the beginning. So instead of /var/... etc. try make sure it's var/... etc. Solution to your problem might be then as follows:

```
<?php
    $str = APPATH.'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    echo substr($str, 1);
?>
```

The second variable at the substr is the startposition of the new string, so that should get rid of the slash at the beginning. Hope this helps!